# After upgrading to 22.04, laptop directly boots Windows 11 with and error message on Lenovo Logo screen

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, grub-efi, 22.04

**Issue:**

During boot I get some error messages and then the laptop boots to Windows 11. I am using a system which has UEFI with secure boot on.

**Error Message:**

```
Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() return Not Found, falling back to default loader
Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

**What I tried:**

I tried Boot repair, It ran for 6 hours but couldn't fix the issue.

I also tried `sudo grub-install`, which gave this error:

`Installing for x86_64-efi platform.`

`grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.`

`sudo update-grub` also didn't worked.

Here's the link to boot repair summary: paste.ubuntu.com/p/WH75ZyYd8B

Boot order in bios menu still shows ubuntu on top and windows boot manager is on second number.

Comment: Switching to Legacy is no solution and can't even be considered here with a dual-boot with Windows 11 which no longer supports Legacy.

Comment: Yup, windows 11 doesn't support legacy. So, please suggest how to fix this issue?

Comment: Reinstall Grub. You may want to use Boot Repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair (better use the 2nd option, install in a live session)

Comment: Tried it. It ran for 6 hours, so I finally closed the boot repair.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

- As @ChanganAuto suggests in a comment, you can try [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) You'll need to run it from an emergency disk (a dedicated Boot Repair disk or the Ubuntu installation disc in its "Try Ubuntu" mode). In theory, it should be able to handle this sort of problem. In practice, I can make no promises, especially if your configuration is odd in any way or if Boot Repair hasn't kept up with recent changes to Ubuntu. (I don't know of any such recent changes that should cause Boot Repair to fail, but it's conceivable there's something about which I don't know.)
- Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) Write this to a CD-R or USB flash drive and boot with it. Depending on how Ubuntu is installed, rEFInd may be able to boot it directly, at which point you can run `sudo grub-install` to re-install GRUB, or install rEFInd, if you prefer. rEFInd might not be able to boot your installation directly, though, particularly if you use an LVM configuration, Btrfs, or some other relatively exotic setup. In such cases, you might need to add options to the kernel boot parameters. You can do this by highlighting the Linux kernel (*not* GRUB) and pressing F2, Insert, or Tab twice. This will open a simple line editor that you can use to add relevant options, like `root=/dev/mapper/lvmname-root` if your root (`/`) filesystem is on a logical volume called `root` on the `lvmname` logical volume. You'll obviously need to know these details to enter them.

If you try Boot Repair and it doesn't work, please post a link to its output. (I haven't used it for a while, but the last time I did, it offered the option to share its log files on a file-sharing site.) This will provide us with clues about what's not working.

Comment: Boot repair didn't worked, and `sudo grub-install` gave this error: `Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.` Here's the link to boot repair summary: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WH75ZyYd8B/

Comment: Have you tried rEFInd, as in my second suggestion? If not, please do. If `grub-install` doesn't work from a rEFInd boot, then try installing rEFInd (via a Debian package or PPA) instead.

Comment: Nothing was working, so reinstalled Ubuntu.